# Bootstrap Page Layout, 100% width menu and image banner with col-lg-8 center main content

Tags: html, css

This is what I am trying to achieve, 
Navigation Menu 100% width, with the menu items spanning the entire width. 

Image banner spanning the entire width of the page. 
Main content only spanning 8 grid units and center.

Looking somewhat like the depiction below.

---

|___________________________________Menu_____________________________________|
|                                                                                                                                                         |
|                                                                                                                                                         |
|                                                           IMAGE BANNER                                                                 |
|                                                                                                                                                         |
|____________________________________________________________________________|

|                                                                                                       |
                          |                                                                                                       |
                          |                                                                                                       |
                          |                    Main Contant Col-lg-8                                                |
                          |                                                                                                       |

What would I use? A jumbotron? with a nav menu?

Comment: Should be 100% width by default, make sure you dont have your nav in another container (bootstrap should take care of removing `body` element padding)

Comment: Thanks Brian! That was what I needed. I had it in a container. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the container from within the nav menu.